# How do I invoke my custom settings provider?

Tags: application-settings, settings.settings, settingsprovider

I need to specify a different location for my settings file.  After many long hours of searching, I found out that I have to write my own SettingsProvider.  I succeeded in creating one which allows me to specify a path for settings file via its constructor. Programatically, I can contruct it like this:

var mycustomprovider = new CustomSettingsProvider(path);

The problem I am having is that there's no way to invoke my custom provider.   I can decorate the VS 2008 generated setting file with the following attribute:

```
[SettingsProvider(typeof(CustomSettingProviders.CustomSettingsProvider))]
internal sealed partial class Settings {
}
```

However, the attribute doesn't allow me to construct the object with a path.  Also, I want to be able to set the SettingsProvider programmatically so that I can pass in any path I want at runtime and save my settings.  The examples I've seen on the net have never mentioned how to use a invoke a SettingsProvider programmatically.